Incoming calls from a specific contact are being blocked, but SMS and outgoing calls to said contact work fine
I've encountered a puzzling issue on my Xiaomi Redmi 9. A single contact in my contact list started getting blocked whenever they tried to call me. When they called, I didn't receive any notification of the call. After it quietly appears in the recent list as blocked.
What's odd:

I can still receive SMS messages from this contact without any
issues.
I can call them without any problems.
This issue only affects incoming calls from this specific contact.

What I've tried:

Double-checked all my block lists to ensure the contact isn't
blocked.

Verified with my service provider that there are no issues on their
end.

Restarted my phone multiple times.


Resolution:
I managed to resolve the issue by completely removing the contact from my phone and re-adding them. After doing this, their calls started coming through normally.
Has anyone else experienced this issue? What could have caused incoming calls from a specific contact to be blocked when they're not on any block list? The contact including a few others who were not blocked were on my starred list. Another question mentioned the combo of starred contacts and the setting for starred contacts to bypass the "Don't Disturb" mode might be a reason.
